# How do I not get a "nonetype" error message

Tags: python

Below I have attached my XML document and the code I am trying to write for it. I want each coworker's name, major, minor, and graduation year printed. Since not every worker has a minor I want to print "N/A" I keep receiving this error message: minor = worker.find('minor').text or "n/a"
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
Here is my XML document:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<workers>
    <worker>
        <name>Susan</name>
        <major>Sociology</major>
        <minor>Spanish</minor>
        <gradyear>2014</gradyear>
    </worker>
    <worker>
        <name>Jeremy</name>
        <major>Neuroscience</major>
        <gradyear>2016</gradyear>
    </worker>
    <worker>
        <name>Leigh</name>
        <major>Kinesiology</major>
        <minor>Business Administration</minor>
        <gradyear>2016</gradyear>
    </worker>
    <worker>
        <name>Kenny</name>
        <major>Biochemistry</major>
        <gradyear>2012</gradyear>
    </worker>
    <worker>
        <name>Sarena</name>
        <major>Finance</major>
        <gradyear>2018</gradyear>
    </worker>
</workers>
```

Here is my code that I have written:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('coworkers.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for student in root.findall('workers'):
        name = worker.find('name').text
        major = worker.find('major').text
        minor = worker.find('minor').text or "n/a"
        gradyear = worker.find('gradyear').text
        print("Workers:", name, "Major:", major, "Minor:", minor, "Graduation year:", gradyear)
```

Comment: What do you understand from that error message? Have you done any debugging?

Answer (score 0):

You need to test whether you got the element first

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('hw7.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for student in root.findall('student'):
        name = student.find('name').text
        major = student.find('major').text
        minor_elem = student.find('minor')
        if minor_elem:
            minor = minor_elem.text 
        else:
            minor = "n/a"
        gradyear = student.find('gradyear').text
        print("Student:", name, "Major:", major, "Minor:", minor, "Graduation year:", gradyear)
```

Or use an exception handler if you prefer

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('hw7.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for student in root.findall('student'):
        name = student.find('name').text
        major = student.find('major').text
        try:
            minor = student.find('minor').text
        except AttributeError:
            minor = "n/a"
        gradyear = student.find('gradyear').text
        print("Student:", name, "Major:", major, "Minor:", minor, "Graduation year:", gradyear)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Using this exception handler worked, I tried to do this earlier but I did not use AttributeError. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The exception tells that some `<student>` element does not even have the `<minor>` attribute, meaning `student.find('minor')` is `None`, then you are trying to call `.text` attribute on `None`. So the best thing to do is use an if-else or try-except block as shown below.

```
# replace this
minor = student.find('minor').text or "n/a" 

# with option 1
minor = student.find('minor').text if student.find('minor') else "n/a"
```

OR

```
# with option 2
try:
    minor = student.find('minor').text
except AttributeError as err:
    minor = "n/a"
    print(f"{name} has no attribute 'minor', because {err} occured") # this is optional though
```